# Prop in children component not updating when calling a function from the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js13

I have an endpoint built with pagination that takes a `page` and `pageSize`. To fetch more items I increase the `page` like so

```
  const loadMore = () => {
    if (page <= totalPages) {
      setPage(page + 1);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCards();
  }, [page]);
```

I also use a modal built with redux that takes a component and it's props. I use it to display the clicked image in a larger format.

To the modal component, I send the: items, the index of the image that was clicked, totalItems, the loadMore function the pageSize, and the currentPage.

```
  const openMoreInfo = (index: number) => {
    dispatch(
      openModal({
        type: 'itemMoreDetails',
        props: {
          items: cards,
          index,
          totalItems: totalElements,
          loadMore,
          pageSize: size,
          currentPage: page,
        },
      })
    );
  };
```

Inside the modal component, I render the item like so:

```
 <img src={items?.[currentIndex]?.ItemImageUrl} alt='' />
```

I also have a `prev button` and a `next button` to navigate through all the images.

```
  const getPrevCard = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prev) => (prev === 0 ? items.length - 1 : prev - 1));
  };

  const getNExtCard = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prev) => (prev === items.length - 1 ? 0 : prev + 1));
  };
```

This works fine until I get to the last index of the first page. After that if `index === pageSize` the next image does not render.

From testing things, I found out that the reason the next card does not render is that the `currentPage` prop does not update inside the children.

This is what I got so far

```
  const getNextCard = () => {
    if (currentIndex + 1 === pageSize! * (pageCount! + 1)) {
      loadMore!();
    }
    setCurrentIndex((prev) => prev + 1);
  };
```

This loads more items in the parent component but the `currentPage` is still not being updated in the modal component. I need to close the modal and click on an image with an index from the second page to have the `currentPage` update.

How can I update the `currentPage` on the `getNextCard` function so I can have access to the indexes from the second page, 3rd page, and so on?

I am using Next13.